# pycharm import code template from pydev?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I decide to switch from pydev to pycharm. I had lots of templates in pydev. Is there any easy way that I can convert the pydev template into pycharm one? I guess the module template in pydev will be the file template, the live template will be all other template in pydev. Is there any good place can download useful templates?

Comment: 3 years later and I'm still surprised at the lack of shared templates. I would love to use them more.